# Thread safety of android default date time formatting?

Tags: android, thread-safety, date-format

I trying to find out is it thread safe to use

```
 DateFormat dateFormat =android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
```

I'm well aware that object [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#synchronization) is not thread safe, but the previous snippet seems quite popular way for writing android programs e.g. [How do you format date and time in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454315/how-do-you-format-date-and-time-in-android/456941#456941), and I haven't noticed any mention of the threading issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Synchronizing on SimpleDateFormat vs. clone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038169/synchronizing-on-simpledateformat-vs-clone)

Comment: @Peter Bear in mind that returned method values is DateFormat, not SimpleDate format. If you can show that the implementation is indeed SimpleDateFormat, I consider the topic resolved.

Comment: You're right. My mistake. Posted an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android.text.format.DateFormat` is a mix of it's own functionality and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. See for yourself: http://www.google.com/codesearch#cZwlSNS7aEw/frameworks/base/core/java/android/text/format/DateFormat.java

As far as I see, it's `format(..)` methods do not use `SimpleDateFormat` nor does it use any instance fields (just some static fields are read), so they should be thread-safe.

Comment: I'll accept this answer as correct one, since source code gives all the necessary information. However, I find the resulting behaviour worrisome, on one hand `format` methods are thread safe; but the `getDateFormat` returns new instance of `SimpleDateFormat` which is not thread safe. The java doc information doesn't event mention threading.