# Parse string to date to filter GAE query

Tags: java, google-app-engine, parsing

I need to filter an App Engine query by a date stamp that I've retrieved from a jsp as (`strDatestamp)`. I know that the Datastore uses UTC time but I'm not sure how to account for this in my parsing. I've tried using `Z`, but this hasn't worked.

```
String strDatestamp = req.getParameter("datestamp");
    String myFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
    Date datestamp = null;
    try {
        datestamp = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormatString, Locale.ENGLISH).parse(strDatestamp);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
Filter filter = new FilterPredicate("date", FilterOperator.EQUAL, datestamp);
Query query = new Query("Example", key)
                .setFilter(filter);
```

Comment: Please provide an example for the content of `strDatestamp`.

Comment: Mon Jul 15 13:44:52 UTC 2013. I've also tried using this parsing "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should parse the example string:

```
 String dt = "Mon Jul 15 13:44:52 UTC 2013";
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
 System.out.println(sdf.parse(dt));
```

Comment: @OP: just note that `SimpleDateFormat` is expensive to initialise, so share it between requests: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107839/synchronizing-access-to-simpledateformat/4108026#4108026