# Unexpected behavior of static member in multithread processing

Tags: java, multithreading, static-members

I have solved an issue about multithread processing at random. I'm happy because it works but I would like to know why. The faulty member in the code below is called `INPUT_SDF`. I thought static final members didn't need synchronized block but when I remove it, everything goes wrong.

```java
public class A implements Comparable<A>
{

    public static final SimpleDateFormat INPUT_SDF  = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);

    ...

    public void setDate(String string) throws ParseException
    {
        synchronized (INPUT_SDF)
        {
            date = INPUT_SDF.parse(string);
        }
    }

}
```

Is my understanding of static final members wrong ? Or is there something else in my code not thread-safe ?

Comment: If you are not stuck with pre-8 Java, then I warmly advise the new Date API, which includes thread-safe parsers and formatters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a field `static final` only makes the *reference* threadsafe; it doesn't synchronize access to the referenced object.

Because instances of SimpleDateFormat are not threadsafe, if an instance is used concurrently by multiple threads, you must synchronize access to it (as you did).

Making the field `static final` just guaranteed that all threads would see the same value for the *reference*.

---

However, your current code is a potential bottleneck, as all threads must queue up to use the instance, possibly yielding worse performance than just creating a new one each time.

If you want to safely reuse instances of SimpleDateFormat, consider using [`ThreadLocal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) to conveniently allow a separate instance to be using for each thread, which would allow you to remove synchronization:

```
private static final ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> formats =
    new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>() {
        @Override protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue() {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
        }
    };

public void setDate(String string) throws ParseException {
    return formats.get().parse(string);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Bohemian, I felt the bottleneck effect but didn't know it. Please allow me to correct a small mistake in your example code : you need to replace the last '}' of field formats by a ';'.

Comment: @Bludwarf indeed - thx for catching that. In my defence, I thumbed that code straight into the answer using my iphone while on the train.

Answer (score 3):

No making fields static final is not enough to make code thread safe.  It only makes the assignment of the reference to an object thread safe, and thus ensures that other threads will see the same object reference within that field.  It does not make mutation of the data stored within the object that was stored in the field (after the assignment) thread safe.  Which is the problem with SimpleDataFormat.

From the documentation of [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

> Date formats are not synchronized. It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally.

If SimpleDateFormat had been stateless, or written to have its state to be thread safe then yes static final would have been enough to be thread safe.

As it is, if one wants to share the same instance of SimpleDataFormat between threads, one must synchronize the threads against the same monitor first.  Otherwise creating a new instance of SimpleDateFormat per thread is recommended, either create a new instance as required or use ThreadLocal or a similar mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

Class [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is not synchronized.

You can take a look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107839/synchronizing-access-to-simpledateformat) for more info.
Hope it helps.